# Sonata Admin - Boolean editable not working after update

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

Boolean edition from list is not working anymore after updating Sonata Admin Bundle to dev-master. I can't click on the field.

Here is my admin class

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('highlighted', 'boolean', ["editable" => true])
    ;
}
```

Here is my composer.json

```
"sonata-project/core-bundle": "dev-master",
"sonata-project/block-bundle" : "dev-master",
"sonata-project/exporter" : "1.3.1",
"sonata-project/jquery-bundle" : "dev-master",
"sonata-project/cache-bundle" : "dev-master",
"sonata-project/intl-bundle" : "dev-master",
"sonata-project/admin-bundle" : "dev-master",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle" : "dev-master"
```

**My question is :** Is it a bundle version problem? Is edition from list just not supported anymore by the latest version of Sonata Admin Bundle? Or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks for you help

Comment: What is the error message you get? Maybe this one? https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2260

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, not with boolean, but with sonata_type_model_list type. It is not working with dev-master. Then I revert doctrine-orm-admin-bundle to latest stable version and now it works.

Solution might be (if you are using doctrine/orm 2.3)

```
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.2.*",
```

if you are using doctrine/orm 2.4

```
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.3.*",
```

Comment: tried but unfortunately it didn't worked. I also tried to get sonata-admin-bundle back to 2.2 but same problem on this version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem too. 
In composer.json I have:

```
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.2.x@dev",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.2.*@dev"
```

All the other bundles will come from dependencies.
Before you run 'composer install', do not forget to run 'composer self-update' and delete the vendors folder!